# Error in controller with angular-google-maps in Angularjs

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, controller

I have a problem with setting up my controller in angular js.

I want to use angular-google-maps (http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/usage)

I have my angular controller like this:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('myApp', ["google-maps"])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [function ($scope) {

    }])
    .controller('MapCtrl', [function ($scope) {

        angular.extend($scope, {
            center: {
                latitude: 0, // initial map center latitude
                longitude: 0, // initial map center longitude
            },
            markers: [], // an array of markers,
            zoom: 8, // the zoom level
        });
    }]);
```

But that doesn't work.
This is what i get:  `Cannot set property 'center' of undefined` 
What would the right way to setup the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing part of the controller for the DI.  Change your controller by adding a string of dependencies before the function.  In this case just `$scope`.

```
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {    //<-- please note the first '$scope'

    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            latitude: 0, // initial map center latitude
            longitude: 0, // initial map center longitude
        },
        markers: [], // an array of markers,
        zoom: 8, // the zoom level
    });
}]);
```

Working Plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/5mdRdrOLRkW6PuLuH3Cv